# Updating Text Labels in D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, force-layout

I have been struggling with this issue for the past couple days:  I have a force directed graph that labels its edges just like [this example](http://console.neo4j.org) does it.  The problem I am facing is that when the graph updates (ie: a node on the graph is added upon a user's click) it updates the graph but it leaves the old edge labels that I wrote previously behind:

**BEFORE & AFTER A NEW GRAPH IS APPENDED:**
[image: BEFORE]
[image: AFTER]

As you can see, my edge labels are hanging around after an update.  I have a function that is called everytime new data comes in, and in this function I have the following code that draws the labels:

```
path_text = svg.selectAll(".path")
.data(force.links(), function(d){ return d.name;})
.enter().append("svg:g");
path_text.append("svg:text")
.attr("class","path-text")
.text(function(d) { return d.data.label; });
```

The svg variable is declared once at a top level closure like so:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");
```

My graph has a tick() function that calculates the location of each label like so:

```
function tick()
    {
            // Line label           
            path_text.attr("transform", function(d) 
            {
                var dx = (d.target.x - d.source.x),
                dy = (d.target.y - d.source.y);
                var dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                var sinus = dy/dr;
                var cosinus = dx/dr;
                var l = d.data.label.length * 6;
                var offset = (1 - (l / dr )) / 2;
                var x=(d.source.x + dx*offset);
                var y=(d.source.y + dy*offset);
                return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ") matrix("+cosinus+", "+sinus+", 

"+-sinus+", "+cosinus+", 0 , 0)";
                });
.
.
.
```

I have tried moving this svg declaration down into the update function, so that this is instantiated each time there is a graph change.  This actually works - but it makes an entire duplicate of the entire graph.  The first, original copy still keeps the old labels - but the second copy acts exactly how I want it to.  Is there a way, perhaps, instead of appending svg, there is a way of replacing?  I have also tried calling  exit().remove() without any luck as well.

Thank you so much for your time.  This has been killing me as to how I'm supposed to do this.

Comment: Did you read the tutorial [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)? You're chaining the enter() selection directly off of the data-join, so you're ignoring the update and exit selections. You need to handle all three states, as described in the tutorial.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed the svg declaration inside my graph update function, attached it to a div, and clear the div before appending it again:

```
jQuery('#v').empty();
var svg = d3.select("#v").append("svg:svg")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");
```

Not the cleanest solution in my opinion, but will go with this unless you all have a better solution!